# Show OneDrive documents shared with me in a cumulated way

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Is there any way to show **OneDrive for Business** all documents shared with me in a "cumulated" way, like a document library, without having to copy files or duplicate content?

Answer (score 2):

In your OneDrive for Business site, there is a link called Shared with Me, that lists all files that have been shared with you from other people's OneDrives.

Comment: Does this link / function exist in SharePoint 2013's On-Premise OneDrive, too?

Comment: I'm not sure if it does currently, I don't have an on-prem 2013 site to check. If it doesn't, it would likely be included in a service pack.

Comment: Did some googling: The function is avaiable on-prem via this link / view in user's personal library: `/personal/<user_id>/Documents/Forms/SharedWithMe.aspx`. Apparently there is no link within the UI itself. Source: [MSDN forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/49b76d83-4827-4713-9666-0e381d0c3049/ssharepoint-2013-shared-with-me?forum=sharepointadmin)

Comment: Yes Eric thank you, but is there any way to integrate it, for example, in a team site, like a normal document library that shows OneDrive documents instead?

Comment: There isn't anything that I know of for that, you might need to roll a custom add-in utilizing the OneDrive API

Comment: I think that is the answer my question Eric, im following that, thanks all.